# jQuery pagination callback

Tags: jquery, callback, pagination

```
$("#News-Pagination").pagination(122, {
   items_per_page:20, 
   callback:handlePaginationClick
});
```

Using this, but on page load `handlePaginationClick` callback function is called each time automatically.

I want that to be only called when user clicks on pagination numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't do anything the first time around:

```
var afterAnnoyingOnLoad = false;
$("#News-Pagination").pagination(122, {
   items_per_page:20, 
   callback: function () {
       if (afterAnnoyingOnLoad) handlePaginationClick();
       else afterAnnoyingOnLoad = true;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
var isLoading = true;
$("#News-Pagination").pagination(122, {
   items_per_page:20, 
   callback:handlePaginationClick
});
...

function handlePaginationClick(new_page_index, pagination_container) {
    if(isLoading){
        isLoading = false;
        return false;   // avoid running this function on page load
    }
...
...
}
```